# No perfect tag for Messenger Platform’s policies

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

We have a lot of doubts concerning the changes in the Messenger Platform’s policies.

There is HUMAN_AGENT tag (for which we have already asked permission) which seems to be the one that adapts the most to our processes, but 7 days is still insufficient for us. Could we answer with this “message_tag” 20 days after a user message? What can we do in this case? We have to find a way not to leave the user without an answer.

We plan on using one of the above-mentioned CONFIRMED_EVENT_UPDATE to answer all user messages outside of the 24 hour window. Are there any penalties for us doing so? If there are, what are the penalties? Are they applied at the company level or the page level? None of the messages sent by our company contain what you want to avoid (spams, special offers, discounts, etc.) so we don’t think we should recieve any penalty even when using “message_tags”.

We have thought about using the normal answer and, if the “This message is sent outside of the allowed window” error message appears, we will answer using “message_tags”. Is there any problem for using the first call on a recurrent basis giving errors or should we avoid it? Avoiding it might cause to send unnecesary “message_tags”. Could we answer all private messages using HUMAN_AGENT when it is approved (our answers are always given by a customer service agent)?

Best regards

Comment: _“Could we answer with this “message_tag” 20 days after a user message?”_ - that will likely be technically restricted, I would not expect anything but an error response if you tried.

Comment: CONFIRMED_EVENT_UPDATE would require that your users actually _subscribed_ to some sort of event. Documentation explicitly lists the following as a non-allowed use case, _“Content related to an event the user has not signed up for (e.g., reminders to purchase event tickets, cross-sell of other events, tour schedules, etc)”_

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention your actual use case, so nobody can suggest any message tags that would match that use case.

Without knowing that use case the answer to your questions can only be:

1) There is no way to extend the 7 days window for human agent tag. If you get approved for it you have a 7 days windows, not 8 and not 20. However most user actions reset that window you should follow up within that window and and make sure the user engages with your bot so the window is reset and you have another 7 days for another update.

2) Abusing tags will most likely result in your page being restricted, make sure to only use them for the allowed use cases as listed in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/message-tags/